# How to open another link in a Webview Android Application?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, webview

My website is having one external link which directs to *api.whatsapp.com* once you click on the chat with us floating button on my website.

I have created a `Webview` Android application that opens my website in it. But when I click on the *Chat With Us* button then it gives me the error as there is no functionality to open it up.

Can anyone please tell me the code to fix this issue?

```
package com.GadgetGlaze.GadgetGlaze;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.gadgetglaze.com/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return `false` in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` when u want to handle links in the browser itself. Try this:

```java
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried changing the "return false" but I am still getting the error.. 

Webpage not available:

The webpage at "URL" could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Please let me know if there is any fixe for this.

Comment: Do you know what is the url you are getting to load in the web view from the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`?

Comment: "whatsapp://send?phone=1234567890=%20Hello%20" is the URL but I think it is calling the Whatsapp application instead of the URL.

Comment: This is the code on my website:

<div class="lp-whatsapp-icon-bar">
     <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=916283918050&text= %20Hello,%20I%20need%20help%20!">
     <img src="https://i.ibb.co/p2zmK5S/whatsapp-icon.png" width="150">
     </a>
    </div>

Comment: `"whatsapp://send` is not allowed on web view. That is why it crashes

Comment: Is there any alternate way to make it work ?